# How to maximize a window to span all monitors (ShowWindow, Win32 api)

Tags: windows, winapi

I use [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/ShowWindowAsync to maximize a window. It works, but for a multiple-monitor setup it fails - it only maximizes to one monitor.

None of the nCmdShow parameters seems to be appropriate.

```
ShowWindowAsync(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Comment: This request doesn't really make sense, because Windows doesn't allow the concept of "maximizing" a window to span multiple monitors. You can programatically resize your window to span all monitors, but it won't be drawn in "maximized" style and beware that the resolution and physical arrangement of the monitors may make it difficult to compute appropriate dimensions.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.  The maximize button works on the Remote Desktop Connection /mstsc window. I'm guessing it does something else then.

Comment: Prior to Windows 7, a Remote Desktop window looks like a single monitor to the target session (regardless of physical monitor configuration of either the server or client).

Comment: Sounds like we have an answer...?

Comment: yes. happy to mark it as an answer if it wasn't a comment :)